# How to correctly return a token and avoid sernario where user clicks button before token loaded

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

// data / api

```
   {"data":{"type":"token","attributes":{"token":"12345678908"}}}
```

This works and my token is sent back to the api

```
  zE('messenger', 'loginUser', function (callback: any) {
    const token = query.data?.attributes?.token
    callback(token)
  })
```

I've had feedback that there is a potential race condition and that I should check the token has loaded first so I tried this but the response.json() does not send me the token but rather

```
async function fetchZendeskToken() {
  const JWT_TOKEN_ENDPOINT = `${query.data?.attributes?.token}`

  const response = await fetch( JWT_TOKEN_ENDPOINT, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json',
    },
  })
  
  console.log('response', response)

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Error fetching zendesk token`)
  }

  const data = await response.json()
  console.log('response', data)
}
```

Console log of the response:

```
Response {type: 'basic', url: 'http://localhost:8080/1234567890', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
```

This does not work now:

```
zE('messenger', 'loginUser', function (callback: any) {
    callback(fetchZendeskToken());
  })
```

Comment: Set a `request_status` variable which will equal `idle`, `pending`, `success` or `error` at any given moment. Change its value to `pending` before you start the `fetch`, change it to `success` if you get a response, or change it to `error` if API returns error or you get a parsing error or something. Make sure that your variable is being "watched" in real time by the UI to trigger the state changes

Comment: Thank you! where would I set the request_status variable?

Answer (score 0):

So basically, you want to track the `lifecycle` of the request and see where it is at, to make an informed update to the UI, and therefore not allow the user to click the button unless the request has been resolved or rejected.

Here is a simple use-case in `vue`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="fetchZendeskToken" :disabled="isFetching">
      Fetch Zendesk Token
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isFetching: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchZendeskToken() {
      try {
        this.isFetching = true;

        const JWT_TOKEN_ENDPOINT = `${query.data?.attributes?.token}`;

        const response = await fetch(JWT_TOKEN_ENDPOINT, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json',
          },
        });

        console.log('response', response);

        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(`Error fetching zendesk token`);
        }

        const data = await response.json();
        console.log('response', data);

        // Here you can update the UI to display "Token fetched successfully", although, successful submits should be signified by a change of screen for better user experience. 

      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);

        // Herem, you can update your UI to display some error message like "Error fetching token" or something similar.

      } finally {
        this.isFetching = false;
        // Once everything is done, you can set the isFetching variable to false.
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```